# Does use of Firebase Auth State Persistence (local or session) option require User cookie consent

Tags: firebase, cookies, firebase-authentication

I am building a web app, and I want to use option  firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL
My question is if it internally uses any Cookie and do I need to show a message to User and get cookie usage consent before I can sign in User with this method.

If User does not provide consent to use Cookie then can I use this
firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION (or does this also require consent to some other cookie type) or  firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE

Simply put, above mentioned 3 options are possible. Is there any cookie consent applicable for this from User?

Thanks
Aniruddh

This is to understand which method of authentication is relevant in accordance with Cookie options

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions about programming and algorithms.  We're not lawyers and can't be trusted to give advice regarding legal or compliance issues.  You should first get an understanding of why "cookie consent" is important for your product and jurisdiction, what implementation details that covers, then question if Firebase Auth meets the specific implementation details.

Comment: Doug is right. While I can say that LOCAL storage doesn't uses local storage and Firebase doesn't use a cookie to send the auth information to the server (it uses the `Authorization` header), whether you need consent is a legal question and means you should consult with your legal council.